# Backbone Routes / View <= Put all my routes inside Views

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, view, routes

Is it reasonable to set the routes inside the view and proceed the events there ?
Want to use a logic to pass the action-url from my views and call a function as callback from my AppRoute Class.

I try to avoid strings as event names and i like to have it easy extensible. So can can create a
view without change the AppRoutes logic.

AppRoutes.js

```
Not working code just for demonstration. 

foreach(view in myViewArry)
{
    route(view.url : view.loadAction);
}
```

View1.js

```
var id = "#View1";
var url = "View1";
function loadAction(id) { logic... };
```

View2.js

```
var id = "#View2";
var url = "View2";
function loadAction(id) { logic... };
```

Comment: "Is it reasonable..." solicits opinion, and runs the risk of generating debate. What's the specific problem you are trying to solve here? (Also, to be a bit pedantic, is this really a TypeScript question? You may be using TS, but the issue appears pure JS / Backbone).

Comment: @JcFx just a setup for webapps in general. i think its better to maintain the website like these. if i like to add a view, i don't have to  make changes in 5 different files just in a central place for the view.

Answer (score 1):

Backbone has routing build into it, so there is no need to mix your routes inside views.

Take a look at the documentation:
http://backbonejs.org/#Router

and this example:
http://backbonetutorials.com/what-is-a-router/

Comment: That's not the answer to my question. Thanks anyway.